# jQuery UI Tabs Ajax - only first tab displaying loaded content

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a set of jQuery UI tabs, which load their content via the ajax method:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/messages/inbox" title="Inbox"><span>Inbox</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/messages/sent" title="Sent"><span>Sent</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/messages/inbox" title="Ins"><span>Ins</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Inbox"> ... </div>
    <div id="Sent"> ... </div>
    <div id="Ins"> ... </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
}
```

The tab titles are displayed, and the content of the first tab is loaded OK.

Using the AJAX Tabs method is detailed [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode)

When I switch to a different tab, I can see the browser loads the content for that tab, but the content isn't displayed.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

replace your ul list by this :

```
 <ul>
        <li><a href="#Inbox" title="Inbox"><span>Inbox</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Sent" title="Sent"><span>Sent</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Ins" title="Ins"><span>Ins</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode specifies that you need to put the ajax content to retrieve in the href, so I don't believe that is correct with the AJAX method.

Comment: for this you don't need to add extra div,just remove div you added after ul list

Comment: Have tried removing the extra divs, and it still exhibits the same behaviour - first one loads fine, others load (I can see it in Chrome Dev Tools), but are not displayed when you click on their tab title.

Answer (score 0):

Have fixed it now. I had a subsequent $.ajaxSetup() call that was upsetting things.